# How to install multiple versions of same app in Bluestacks W7

Tags: windows-7, bluestacks

Been looking around for a while trying to find a solution to run and install multiple versions of same app in Bluestacks. My intention is to run the apps one at a time. I found almost what I looked for with the Wizard http://www.thewizardsmanse.com/multiple-app-accounts-using-bluestacks/ but could not get it to work more than that Bluestacks got corrupted. I would like to try it out on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameforge.xmobile.war&hl=nl_NL . Any idea or recommendation would be gratefully appreciated.

Running latest Bluestacks on OS W7

All the best!

Comment: Wondering the same thing, will look into it tomorrow.